# Qual a diferença entre " - " e " / " nos comandos do CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

Qual a diferença de usar o `-` e a `/` no CMD por exemplo no comando:

```
shutdown -s
```

ou

```
shutdown /s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originalmente, em sistemas DOS/Windows é usado o `/` para complementar os comandos, enquanto que em outros sistemas como sistemas baseados em Unix, é  usado o `-` para complementar os comandos. Porém o `/` é apenas uma convenção( P.ex.: `ipconfig /all`), possibilitando o uso de parâmetros via `-`. Geralmente o uso de `-` como parâmetro serve mais como uma maneira de tornar o código mais próximo de sistemas POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um **característica** do comando `shutdown`, o programa interpreta como quiser, por exemplo se você criar um programa em Python (3):

```
import sys

print ("\n".join(sys.argv))
```

E chamar assim no terminal ou cmd:

```
python arquivo.py -foo -bar -baz
```

irá imprimir isto:

```
-foo
-bar
-baz
```

Se fizer isto

```
python arquivo.py /foo /bar /baz
```

Irá imprimir isto:

```
/foo
/bar
/baz
```

Ou seja o programa internamente recebe como descrito para cada espaçamento, mas ele é quem trata internamente, então provavelmente ele irá identificar `/s` e `-s` como sendo o mesmo, se assim desejar, usando `if` ou `switch` ou o que a linguagem suportar.

O `shutdown` especificamente provavelmente suporta ambos por questões de facilidade e/ou portabilidade entre as versões do Windows, não é necessariamente um problema de programação, mas sim um escolha pessoal de quem desenvolveu (a microsoft ?!)